# How do I dynamically update the text in a TextBlock control (C# - WPF)

Tags: c#, dynamic, textblock

I have a property called Scroller defined as shown below.  I have a for loop and would like to be able to update the contents of the control dynamically.

I would like the contents of this control to refresh through each for iteration.
At the moment the TextBlock shows the contents after the for... loop exists and program terminates.

How can I do it please?

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="Scroller" Margin="0,90,0,57">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Output" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" Width="{Binding ElementName=Scroller, Path=ViewportWidth}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

EDIT:

I'm adding a functional solution to help demonstrate my problem. Sorry if my original question was not sufficiently clear.

```
<Window x:Class="RdElectReg.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RdElectReg"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Start" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="419,56,23,0" Click="Button_Click" IsDefault="True"/>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="Scroller" Margin="0,90,0,57">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Output" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" Width="{Binding ElementName=Scroller, Path=ViewportWidth}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The above is the the xaml file and below is the code.

```
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows;

    namespace RdElectReg
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(ProcessFile(i));
            }
        }

         private StringBuilder ProcessFile(int i)
        {
            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
            string TextBlockText = Output.Text;
            TextBlockText = TextBlockText + "Processing iteration " + i.ToString() + "\n";
            // this property
            Output.Text = TextBlockText;

            for (int j = 1; j < 1000; j++) {
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Remove(sb1.Length - 1, 1);
                sb1.AppendLine();
            }

            return sb1;
        }
    }
}
```

Each time the function ProcessFile is called it takes the contents of the TextBlock, adds some text and updates the TextBlock.

```
string TextBlockText = Output.Text;
TextBlockText = TextBlockText + "Processing iteration " + i.ToString() + "\n";
// this property
Output.Text = TextBlockText;
```

My problem is that during program execution the TextBlock does not dynamically update. The updated text only appears in the form **after** the program has finished executing.

I would like the TextBlock to update dynamically.

I hope this helps clarify my problem.

Comment: don't try to edit your code into FreekW. 's answer, add it in your question. I rejected your edit

Answer (score 0):

```
Output.Content = "foobar";
```

This what you mean?

EDIT: Please add some more code so we can actually see what you're doing in your for loop.

Comment: Maybe because you are not calling the function on load time, but rather on a click event? <pre>private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }<code>

Comment: Or do you mean you want it to update during the loop? In that case just add the text you want to update during the loop. <pre>TextBlockText = TextBlockText + "Processing iteration " + i.ToString() + "\n";<code>
Add that in the for loop.

Comment: If I don't include the background thread functionality I don't get the textblock updating dynamically **while the program is executing**.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution from the posting at [Updating value of TextBlock in wpf dynamically [Sovled]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477276/updating-value-of-textblock-in-wpf-dynamically-sovled).

This is the modified solution (XAML):

```
<Window x:Class="RdElectReg.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RdElectReg"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Start" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="419,56,23,0" Click="Button_Click" IsDefault="True"/>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="Scroller" Margin="0,90,0,57">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Output" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" Width="{Binding ElementName=Scroller, Path=ViewportWidth}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Textstr}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Page (Italic code shows the additional instructions to make it happen):

```
using System.Text;
*using System.Threading;*
using System.Windows;

namespace RdElectReg
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        *Progress viewModel = new Progress();*

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            *this.DataContext = viewModel;*
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            */// Background thread Thread to run your logic 
            Thread thread = new Thread(YourLogicToUpdateTextBlock);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();*
        }
        *// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477276/updating-value-of-textblock-in-wpf-dynamically-sovled*
        private void YourLogicToUpdateTextBlock()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                viewModel.Textstr = viewModel.Textstr + "Processing iteration " + i.ToString() + "\n";
                sb.Append(ProcessFile(i));
            }
            viewModel.Textstr = viewModel.Textstr + "DONE\n";
        }

        private StringBuilder ProcessFile(int i)
        {
            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

            for (int j = 1; j < 10000; j++) {
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Append(j.ToString() + ",");
                sb1.Remove(sb1.Length - 1, 1);
                sb1.AppendLine();
            }

            return sb1;
        }
    }
}
```

The class Progress is databound to the textblock. The class is shown hereunder:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace RdElectReg
{
    class Progress : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _textstr = "";

        public Progress()
        {
            _textstr = "";
        }

        public Progress(string text)
        {
            _textstr = text;
        }

        public string Textstr
        {
            get
            {
                return _textstr;
            }
            set
            {
                _textstr = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Textstr");
            }
        }

        // property changed event
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                // Raise the PropertyChanged event
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }

     }
}
```

My interpretation of the solution is that:

1. the TextBlock is data bound to the property Textstr of the class Progress
2. The class is instantiated in the code and using this.DataContext is abound to the TextBlock
3. The main logic of the solution (what was origially in Button_Click in my case) is executed as a background thread.